# Relation between Sleeping pattern and attention for ADHD people

Tags: sleep, attention, adhd

Question 1:
Does sleeping at different times daily affect the attention for ADHD and Non ADHD ?

For example let us consider the below scenario,

**Day 1** : Sleep time is 1:00 AM

**Day 2** : Sleep time is 2:00 AM

**Day 3** : Sleep time is 4:00 AM

**Day 4** : Sleep time is 12:30 AM

**Day 4**:  Sleep time is 2:00 AM

Do such patterns affect the attention for ADHD people ?

*Note: Provided that the sleep time is 6- 7 hours per day *

Question 2

Can we compromise the lost sleep ?

Comment: The old advice for sanity and health is: "Go to bed the same day you get up." your example goes against that.